# Javascript objects: Is there any difference between setting an objects property from inside a function or by its return value

Tags: javascript-objects

Setting a property named 'sample' to 1 :

Way 1:

```
function Collection() {
    this.sample = function() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Way 2:

```
function Collection() {
    this.sample = function() {
        this.sample = 1;
    }
}
```

Will there be any there any difference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing different things:

In the first example, you have a FUNCTION which is RETURNING the number '1'.

In the second example, you're setting the MEMBER 'sample' of your object to '1'.

Also, when you call object.sample (example #2) for the first time, you will receive nil instead of '1', as you're calling the function which is setting the member.

After the first call, you'll receive the number '1' whenever you're accessing 'sample'.

Answer (score 2):

In the second case, you can only call `obj.sample()` once; after that you would be trying to call the number 1.

```
var obj = new Collection();
var one = obj.sample();
var again = obj.sample();
```

In the first case, both `one` and `again` end up being 1; in the second case an exception occurs on the third line ("Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function").

Answer (score 1):

Huge difference: your first assignment will end up with you setting this.sample to be a function returning 1, and your second assignment will end up setting this.sample to be a function setting this.sample = 1 (losing the reference to to anonymous function built in your constructor), and returning undefined.

So, for "way 1":

```
var c = new Collection();
console.log(c.sample());  // logs "1"
console.log(c.sample());  // logs "1" again
```

and "way 2":

```
var c = new Collection();
console.log(c.sample());  // logs nothing (undefined doesn't print anything, iirc)
console.log(c.sample());  // throws an error, since "1" is not a function
```

Comment: I have to say, based on what you've written here, it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: my actual intention was to set value 1 for the property,

Thank you

Comment: Then you want to simply define Collection like this:

    function Collection() { this.sample = 1; }

no nested function required.

Comment: yes, thats right.
sorry for one thing that caused confusion,
when i said 'my actual intention', i *actually* indicated this question.
what i was doing that made me ask this question: i was writing a constructor function(lets say its name is Collection ) , quite lengthy for me(i started to study javascript just some days ago)

there, value of a property is to be set after some lengthy calculations so to be inside a function,
but then i thought "what will happen if i either return the result or set the result",
which i couldn't figure out quickly, i was messing around

Thank You